# MaskedAutoencoderViT inference

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, autoencoder

There is a lot of examples how to evaluate mae-vit models on full image (like [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/mae/blob/efb2a8062c206524e35e47d04501ed4f544c0ae8/demo/mae_visualize.ipynb))

But I can't find anywhere inference of those models on images with missing values.

E.g:

```
# load an image
img_url = 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11435359/147738734-196fd92f-9260-48d5-ba7e-bf103d29364d.jpg' # fox, from ILSVRC2012_val_00046145
img = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream=True).raw)
img = img.resize((224, 224))
img = np.array(img) / 255.
     
# load model
checkpoint = torch.load(chkpt_dir, map_location='cpu')
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'], strict=False)

# image with missing patch
img[15:30, :, :] = np.nan
mask = np.zeros(img.shape)
mask[15:30, :, :] = 1

# How to predict missing patch? like model(img, mask)
....
```

All examples I found use full image as input and return loss, prediction and mask `loss, y, mask = model(x, mask_ratio=0.75)`
,but nowhere I can't find something like `prediction = model(img, mask)`